# Terraform: Encrypted flag cannot be specified since device /dev/sda1 has a snapshot specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am migrating my **Autoscaling groups** to use **launch_template** instead of **launch_configuration**. (*To support T2 Unlimited*)

Below is my code snippet.

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "test_launch_template" {
  image_id = "ami_id"
  name_prefix     = "test-pref"
  instance_type   = "t2.small"
  key_name        = "jayesh"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-23423432","sg-23452115"]
  user_data       = "${base64encode(data.template_file.user_data.rendered)}"
  
  iam_instance_profile {
    name = "test"
  } 
  disable_api_termination = true
  instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = "terminate"

  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"
    ebs {
      delete_on_termination = true
      volume_size           = "${var.volume_size}"
    }
  }
    
  credit_specification {
    cpu_credits = "unlimited"
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = "true"
  }  
}
```

While running terraform apply I am getting below error.

> 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> aws_autoscaling_group.test_asg: 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> aws_autoscaling_group.test_asg: Error creating AutoScaling Group:
>
> ValidationError: You must use a valid fully-formed launch template.
> the encrypted flag cannot be specified since device /dev/sda1 has a snapshot specified.
>
> status code: 400, request id: 7902a390-58de-11e8-af77-87d327f8b121

May be any parameter is missing but i am not sure which one.

As per error, It looks that encrypted parameter is specified. But i haven't passed that. Then why this error is coming?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a `Snapshot` attached to the AMI that i am passing while creating `launch template`. Is that causing the issue?

Comment: Your error is indicating an issue while creating the autoscaling group but the code you provided is for lunch template only. Am i missing something?